# Access Object from meteor main app in package

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, package, meteorite

So I'm developing a meteor app right now which is based on several different packages.

I have an object in my main application which I use as a kind of API for the packages. This object looks like this (in lib/helpers/api.coffee inside the main application):

```
@Mainapp =
  getCurrentUser: ->
  Meteor.user()

  getCurrentUserId: ->
  Meteor.userId()

  setTitle: (title) ->
  setTitle(title)

  setAlert: (message, type='danger') ->
  Alerts.add(message, type)
```

If I access this object in the Mainapp or in the console, everything works as expected.
But If I try to access this object inside a package for the application I get a "Mainapp not defined"-Error.

Is there a way to share this object between the main application and the packages. I know that I can do something with session.set and session.get but I think that it is better to have a central object which acts as a kind of API for my packages.

There is Meteor.userId() and Meteor.user() which does something similar for the Meteor core-System (those functions are also available in a package). How do they achieve that this functionality is available in the Meteor main app and in the packages?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found out what the problem was.

The object-Variable needs to be globally available (as marcodejongh pointed out correctly).

What I did wrong was that I called functionality encapsulated in the object directly in the file (without a function or anything else --> on file-Load).

```
Mainapp.getCurrentUserId()
```

What solved my issue is to use the functionality in e.g. a function.

```
# inside an iron-router routes
Router.map ->
  @route 'index',
  controller: IndexController
  path: '/index'
  onAfterAction: ->
    Mainapp.setTitle 'Test'
```

Meteor first build all your packages. At this point in time the Mainapp-Object was not accessible. After building the package and embedding it in the Mainapp, the function is available.

Answer (score 1):

Make Mainapp globally accessible. So the javascript generated by your example should be:

```
var constructor = function () {
}
constructor.prototype.getCurrentUser= function () {.....
.... DEFINE YOUR METHODS ....

Mainapp = new constructor();
```

Meteor does magic with variables without a var in front of it and makes them globally accessible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You're right. The Variable needs to be globally accessible.  I've found out that I called the Object in a wrong way. My answer below is more detailed what I did wrong.